# Listening for events on dynamic elements with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tether

I am using Vuejs and Drop.js (which uses Tether.js).
Drop creates it's own DOM elements, if they don't exist.

I created a template for drop's content (to add to the dropdown when a button is clicked)

I am trying to listen to the click event for a button in the dropdown.

I created a new `Vue` with the `el` as the `body` tag. This does not work. How do I listen for clicks on dynamically added dom elements with vuejs?

Comment: have a look at this - http://forum.vuejs.org/topic/151/vue-js-not-listening-to-dynamically-created-elements/2

Comment: @mic4ael: Oh bummer.